# Conflict with Mootools accordian and Jquery

Tags: jquery, mootools, accordion

I am using mootools only for accordion .

script on separate page without any query works fine but the page on which has Jquery is causing lots of issues . I tried various variations but the error persists

```
<script src="js/mootools-art-0.87.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/mootools-core-1.4-full.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/mootools-more-1.4-full.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/main.js"></script>


     <script type="text/javascript">
         jQuery.noConflict()
         (window.addEvent('domready', function () {
             new Fx.Accordion(jQuery('accordion'), '#accordion h2', '#accordion .content');
         })(jQuery);

    </script>
```

Error on browser console

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: Class is not defined mootools-art-0.87.js:182
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ; navigation-test.html:30
event.returnValue is deprecated. Please use the standard event.preventDefault() instead.
```

Comment: your problem __#1__ is that `mootools-art-0.87.js` is loading before core, put that .js file after core and more.

Comment: your problem __#2__ is that you are using the wrong selector in the Accordion, replace `jQuery('accordion')` with `document.id('accordion')`

Comment: and, btw, you might want do do `var myAccordion= new Fx.Accordion( //etc` just so you can call it later if needed.

Comment: why are you passing jquery into a mootools only closure? if you don't know how to select an element by id in mootools, it's `document.id('someid')` for a single element. $$ returns a COLLECTION which supports iteration and may work in some cases but it's not a solution for a single element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem #1 is that `mootools-art-0.87.js` is loading before `core`, put that `.js` file after `core` and `more`.

Your problem #2 is that you are using the wrong selector in the Accordion, replace `jQuery('accordion')` with `document.id('accordion')`.
`jQuery('#accordion')`, with a `#` would work but don't mix jQuery there.

And, btw, you might want do do `var myAccordion= new Fx.Accordion( //etc` just so you can call it later if needed.

Comment: it still is the same , the div I am using is  <div id="accordion">  , its perfectly working in separate page with no Jquery files referenced

Comment: I cant remember ,but from another thread I used this: replace all $ with $$ in mootools files, now on event click it is refering into Jquery file

Comment: it is refernh now to Jquery file like this function (e){return typeof b===i||e&&b.event.triggered===e.type?t:b.event.dispatch.apply(f.elem,arguments)}
arguments: null

Comment: after reproducing the use case with your solution the error is this :Uncaught TypeError: Object function (e,t){return this.each(function(){b.event.trigger(e,t,this)})} has no method 'indexOf' mootools-more-1.4-full.js:81
event.returnValue is deprecated. Please use the standard event.preventDefault() instead.

Comment: Changing all `$` to `$$` is a `no-no`. Mootools uses `$` in the accordion first parameter and it's the corresponding `getElementByID` and should be changed to the Mootools `document.id` to avoid using the `$`. Check around in your code if you might have made incorrect Mootools `$` to `$$` thinking they were from jQuery. Please make a fiddle or post a link that reproduces your error.